# Is preloading / precaching can be bad for my web applications

Tags: web-applications

With web browsers trying to be faster and faster more and more resources are pre[loaded|cached|fetched].

I use CodeIgniter for my web applications and I've built my controllers so that www.mysite.com/users/delete/10 will delete the user #10

My question is the following: will this page ever (either in one year or ten years) be precached by a web browser so that displaying my list of users will also delete them all (for example).

I know it's a pretty subjective question but it's pretty essential I think.

Thanks for your enlightenment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the reason why there are [different HTTP *verbs*,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http#Request_methods) and why only GET requests are considered idempotent*. I.e. it is expected that you can issue the same GET request as many times as you like, getting the same result. Browsers, search engines and everything else expects requests to work this way, so **don't modify or delete data on a GET request**. Because yes, prefetching or indexing by search engines would delete all your data, which has been the cause of [many laughs around the interwebs](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/WellIntentioned-Destruction.aspx) for about as long as search engines exist.

To add new data, you should use POST requests. To modify existing data, PUT requests. To delete data, DELETE requests. In practice PUT and DELETE are not really supported by browsers, so those usually all become POST requests. But at the very least not GET requests.

<sub>* Not considering HEAD requests and such.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Any "REST-ful" access to any of your web pages should never, "by itself, just because you happen to be here," *do* something.  There needs to be something more:  for example, an active, authenticated, not-yet-expired session.  (i.e. "You must be logged-in, *and* you must be God Himself.")  If you are not, then the request is refused... period.

Presentation of an appropriately-formed RESTful URL might be a sufficient way to *present* the request to your back-end system, but that does not dictate that the request, having been presented, should be *obeyed!*

Comment: More than being authenticated and all that, this should be a POST or DELETE request. A GET request must not modify anything.